# Is "would" the past future tense of "will" or just a modal verb?

Tags: differences, past-tense, modal-verbs

What's the difference between the following sentences?

> 1. Would you give me some advice?
> 2. Will you give me some advices?

Comment: What is the past future tense?

Comment: My textbook just tell me there are 16 kinds of tenses in English. see: http://www.louhau.edu.mo/www/discol/english/past/past_future_tense.htm

Comment: I am not mother-tongue, but I believe that an example of past future tense could be: "Next year, I shall send you a letter indicating where I *shall have gone* on holiday"

Comment: @Sklivvz Nope. What they mean by past future, I think, is the result of English sequence of tense for subordinate clauses. For instance, a main clause in the future “I will go to see the mayor” will become the following when used a subordinate clause in secondary sequence: “I said I would see the mayor”.

Comment: By the way, the whole idea of a past future tense is nonsense, but that works in English because we only have two true elementary tenses: past and non-past. All of our other tenses are formed periphrastically, which makes a “past future” just the past analogue to a periphrasis which denotes the future.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, The future of the past.

Comment: @Pacerier _Past Future tense_ is not a term used in English grammar. (Somebody will also tell you that English doesn't have any Future tense, though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Would* can be either conditional or subjunctive, but it is often used (as your examples demonstrate) interchangeably with *will*.

*Will* is an inquiry after the consent of the respondent, whose inclinations comprise the sole issue at hand. "Will you give me some advice?" literally means it is up to "your" discretion either to give or withhold the advice.

"Would you give me some advice?" on the other hand implies some other conditions may affect your decision. Unstated but implied in this sentence may be some other information. Or there may be a contextual linkage or even a direct statement. I think of Dr. Seuss's *Green Eggs and Ham*:

> Would you eat them in a box?
>   Would you eat them with a fox?

The terms of the conditional are clearly set forth. The questioner is proffering various inducements to sweeten the deal for the recalcitrant hater of "Sam-I-Am".

In any case, asking either question in conversation will, in the vast majority of cases, be understood simply as a request for advice, without all the grammatical analysis.

Comment: Does the "would" mean a past future tense? PS:Your logo means "dream" in CJK(Chinese/Japanese/Korean) :)

Comment: @lovespring: No, the "would" does not mean a "past future tense"; it can help in such constructions as "would have been" or "would have done" and so on. And yes, I'm aware what my avatar means. In Japanese it's *yume*, pronounced "yu-meh".

Comment: How could I different it from the past tense of "will"? because they two share the some form.

Comment: @lovespring: I'm not sure what you're asking me? Where are you having problems with differentiating the various uses of *would*?

Comment: Yes, How could i know the 'would' is used as an modal auxiliary or just the past tense form of the 'will'?

Comment: would cannot be subjunctive - it is a common error to say "if I would do X" to mean "if I were to do X".  Note however, "if he would do X" vs "if he were to do X" are quite different and only the latter is subjunctive - the first is the past tense of will in the sense of an act of will - the problem is he won't!

Answer (score 5):

Conventionally, *would* can be either the **past simple** or the **past subjunctive** of *will*. To put it very simply, it is best considered past simple if you are looking forward from a past perspective in a story. In that case, it is used in the middle of a narrative that is in the past tense. Both the narrative and *would* are then simply a description of the past; what would be *will* in a narrative in the present tense becomes *would*:

> - She said she would succeed. *(In direct speech it would be: `She said: "I will succeed"`.)*
> - He knew they would find him eventually. *(In direct speech it would be: `He thought: "I know they will find me eventually"`.)*

In most other cases, it is past subjunctive. This tense can be used in several ways, of which the conditional is the most frequent:

> - If he were rich, he would still be a
>   bastard. *(The conditional is used to express that "he will still be a bastard" is only true if the "if" condition is fulfilled.)*
> - She would like some more tea. *(Here
>   there is some implied condition, such
>   as "if you asked her", "if it were
>   possible", "if she were permitted to
>   speak", "if it weren't rude", etc.;
>   that is why conditional past
>   subjunctives are often used to express
>   politeness.)*

All the above generally applies equally to the other modal verbs, *can*, *shall*, and *may*.

If you say "will you give me some advice?", this is a perfectly fine and polite request, though perhaps a tiny bit old fashioned. It could theoretically be a question about the other person's desire, but context makes it clear that this is not what is intended.

"Would you give me some advice?" is an attempt at even greater politeness, because the conditional makes the request even more tentative, as explained above. Take your pick.

Comment: There's a thread elaborating on the politeness level of each construction: https://englishtips.quora.com/If-+-Would-vs-Will-vs-Would-Have

Comment: @Cerberus
"what would be will in a narrative in the present tense becomes would" beautifully put! thanks

Comment: @ehsan88: Good!

Answer (score 1):

Either would or will work, but you wouldn't change the noun:

> Would you give me some advice?

and

> Will you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

> Is “would” the past future tense of “will” or just a modal verb?

*Would* is the past tense of *will* in sentences like

> He said he would be away for a couple of days.
>   He wanted out, but she wouldn't leave.

The difference between *Would you give me some advice?* and *Will you give me some advice?* is that the first is considered a polite way to ask help, while the second (depending on the context) could be also understood as expressing desire, consent, or willingness.

> Will you have a cognac?

Comment: Your answer has "advice"  yet in the edit you performed on the OP both sentences were changed to "advises" which is the 3rd person singular of the verb "to advise."

Comment: @Mari-LouA That was the automatic corrector I triggered by mistake.

Comment: So the grammarchecker or the spellchecker corrected something that was correct in the first place? I'm talking about the first sentence.

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that word was changed.

Answer (score -3):

> Yes, How could i know the 'would' is
>   used as an modal auxiliary or just the
>   past tense form of the 'will'?

There is a very easy way to tell. Modal verbs have no tense. In modern English, all modal verbs are tenseless. There are no past tense forms or present tense forms. In older forms of English, modals did have tense, so we can accurately refer to modern modals as "historical past tense forms" or "historical present tense forms".

It's easy to prove this because no one can make a sentence in English where any one of the purported past tense modals acts as a real past tense.

Where modals seem like they are being used as a past tense, in reporting speech, they aren't really acting as past tense. They are simply being used the same as the past tense FORM of lexical verbs in a process called backshifting, to signal that the speech is not direct/quoted but rather it is indirect/reported.

The difference between "Would you give me some advice?" and "Will you give me some advice?"
is only one of level of politeness/deference. As the historical past tense forms, in their epistemic [level of certainty] meanings show a greater sense of doubt/certainty, that same doubt/uncertainty carries over to modal deontic [social] meaning so they are considered more polite/more deferential/softer/less direct.

Comment: I don't know where you are getting these ideas. "I told him that I would meet him in the city on Tuesday." — This is a past tense usage of *will*. "I couldn't watch my favorite show yesterday." — This is a past tense usage of *can*.

Comment: "They are simply being used the same as the past tense FORM of lexical verbs in a process called backshifting, to signal that the speech is not direct/quoted but rather it is indirect/reported." — Then why do we say *I am telling her that he will never leave his wife*? It is indirect speech, and yet I see "will", not "would". Transposing this sentence to the past may give "would": *I was telling her that he would never leave his wife. Of course it turned out I was right*.