# Why is the subjunctive mood considered tenseless? Is "would be able to" not explicitly a future (perfect) construction?

Tags: tenses, conditionals, subjunctive-mood, inflectional-morphology, finite-verbs

I've read through the responses on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/is-would-the-past-future-tense-of-will-or-just-a-modal-verb), but I don't feel like they address the idea that English subjunctive clauses lack inflection (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Grammatical_composition)).

I'm looking at this sentence, for example:

> In the case that any service impact arises from this, it would be able to be mitigated within 20 minutes.

The sentence clearly conveys a hypothetical future condition, with "would be able" constructed in a perspective that's either contemporary to that future condition or looking back to a past (but still in the future) event. I'm not sure which of those is the correct reading, though – or whether either of them is at all.

In either case, there is a clearly tensed construction distinct from other forms of the subjunctive, isn't there? Even if it's syncretic with constructions in other tenses, it still seems to carry a distinct meaning.

As a secondary question, is there really no simpler way to convey "would be able to be" in English? It seems very verbose for such a simple concept. This sentence also comes from an impromptu technical write up; it's possible it's just not a grammatically standard sentence in the first place.

Comment: Is that a subjunctive mood or a conditional mood?

Comment: The fact that you used tensed verbs indicates that this *isn't* the subjunctive.

Comment: This question is misconceived so no point answering. But instead of "it would be able to be mitigated" you might say "it could be mitigated" (or possibly "it should be mitigated" depending on exactly what you mean by "would be able").

Comment: Simplify: "If this causes a service impact, it can be mitigated within 20 minutes."

Comment: Put it in the active voice to better see... *If any service impact arises from this, the system will be able to mitigate it.*  / Subjunctive: *If any service impact were to arise from this, the system would be able to mitigate it.*  / And since the system is able to mitigate it whether something goes wrong or not, better would be: *If any service impact arises from this, the system will mitigate it.*  / Subjunctive: *If any service impact were to arise from this, the system would mitigate it.*

Comment: I don't follow you. There's no subjunctive clause in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Inflection, as you know, can involve changes in the form of verbs, nouns and adjectives.  Verbs can be changed depending on Person (first, second or third **person**), Number (singular or plural - except ancient Greek, which had an additional number for referring to pairs, known as the 'dual', Tense (present, imperfect, future, perfect/aorist - in French - , pluperfect, future perfect), Voice (active and passive),  Mood - now called 'mode' or 'modality' - Indicative and Subjunctive (except for ancient Greek, which had these two plus an *optative* mood used for remote (unikely) conditionals and, as the name suggests, wishes (literally, "if only..".  Rupert Booke used an anglicised ancient Greek optative in his yearning poem to Granchester.

> *Eithe genoimayn* [Ειθε γενοιμην], would I were / in Granchester in Granchester...

There must be other languages, ancient or modern, with more moods/modes than this. And I have said nothing of the second person (singular and plural imperatives). Nevertheless, the European languages I know of have far fewer than Latin, let alone ancient Greek.

English has what is called a *mode* or modal usage involving a form of the verbs *be*, *have* and *can* (*were*, *had* and *could*), as modal auxiliaries, together with *would* which which is the past and modal form of *will*, as set out in Etymonline

> would
> Old English wolde, past tense and past subjunctive of willan "to will" (see will (v.)). Would-be (adj.) "wishing to be, vainly pretending" is first recorded c. 1300.

> could (v.)
> Old English cuðe, past tense of cunnan "to be able" (see can (v.1)); ending changed 14c. to standard English -d(e). The unetymological -l- was added 15c.-16c. on model of would, should, where it is historical. Could be as a response to a suggestion, indicating it may be correct, is by 1938.

Historically, European, including grammarians, had a disconcerting habit of trying to match the grammar of English to the Latin and often Greek that many of them had learned.  Isaac Newton was not a classicist (or a grammarian) but published is epoch-making *Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica in - yes - Latin.

There is no future form of the Latin or Greek subjunctive (though the ancient Greek optative performs the role of a modal reference to the future). It has turned out over the centuries that this whole panoply is not necessary.  English is an extreme case, in which it has turned out that all you need is the past tenses of the four auxiliary verbs, *will, can, be and have*. [*Would* is etymologically the past of *will* as shown in the article in Etymonline].

So the modal use of would is wedded to the word will and does, in fact, point to the future.  It is a strange paradox that it can also point to the past in non modal context.  This is an example ofhow heavily English grammar depends on context.

> They would take their dog for a walk across the fields even when it was raining. Obviously indicative about a past habit.

> Would you lend me your Rolls Royce, if I let you stay in my chalet?  Obviously 'modal' (even now some still call it subjunctive) referring to the future.

In fact, in this sentence is actually ambiguous, because let has the same present and past form of 'let'.  Except for the 3rd person singular, which is *s/he lets* in the present but *s/he let* in the past and so also in the subjunctive/modal use. To avoid ambiguity, you would insert something like *were to*: ...if I **were to let you stay ...?**

You have brought to attention that the English language is grammatically much untidier than our teachers might have us believe.  That is not their fault. they are trying make it simple enough for young people to understand and learn, and simplicity implies rules.  There are rules, or at least patterns, but in the case of English they come with dozens of exceptions - more than in the few European languages of which I have any knowledge.

So how does "were" point forwards to the future?  Well, that is how people speak. Usually, where there is a possible ambiguity, we we take evasive action to make things clear.  You might say "If I were **to** come round tomorrow, would you be able to spare me half an hour?".  But I doubt whether most people would go that far.